# How to debug a referenced strong name DLL?

Tags: .net, debugging

My solution uses [Bundle Transformer: Autoprefixer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Autoprefixer/), which indirectly references [ClearScript](https://clearscript.codeplex.com/).

I'm fine with Bundle Transformer: Autoprefixer, but want to debug ClearScript. I've download its source code, but if in my solution I reference the ClearScript project instead of the strong name DLL, Autoprefixer DLL is unable to load ClearScript DLL, giving error

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScript, Version=5.4.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=935d0c957da47c73' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Of cause, because the dll my ClearScript project compiles to doesn't have such public key token.

Is there an easy way to debug ClearScript?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

If the source is available for ClearScript, you can get the symbols, and the source has been indexed you can [setup the Symbol File Locations in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx) to download the sources while debugging.

For example, my sources look like this:

[image: Visual Studio Source File Location Options]

These sources allow me to load many symbols and sources of Nuget packages and Microsoft assemblies during debugging. You can also add local paths if you have the source and matching PDB files.

If the source is not available, or no source server has indexed them, you can use [DotPeek to load the assembly and generate PDBs and run as a local symbol server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/2016.1/Symbol_Server_and_PDB_Generation.html). Then you can configure Visual Studio to use it to load symbols from. [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) will automatically decompile the assembly and serve up source you can debug from within Visual Studio.